# how to to use multiple filter (using dropdown) for html table

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#mylist {
  
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>dish filter</h2>
<select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
<option value="">ALL</option>
<option value="fish">fish</option>
<option value="chicken">chicken</option>

</select>
<h2>receiver filter</h2>
<select id="mylist1" onchange="namefilter()" class='form-control'>
<option value="">ALL</option>
<option value="receiver1">receiver1</option>
<option value="receiver2">receiver2</option>
<option value="receiver3">receiver3</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">receiver</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">dish</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>receiver1</td>
    <td>fish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>receiver1</td>
    <td>fish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>receiver2</td>
    <td>chicken</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>receiver2</td>
    <td>chicken</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>receiver3</td>
    <td>fish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>receiver3</td>
    <td>chicken</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
     if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
function namefilter() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist1");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
     if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Description

1. In the above program I have been trying to filter with multiple dropdown but after i select fish from dish filter it showing receiver1,reciver2 in name filter column but if i select receiver3 in receiver filter it showing receiver 3 I only need to filter what's displaying row instead of invisible rows

### In short i need to use multiple filters to filter html table

Comment: you can use Select2 or https://codepen.io/creativekinetix/pen/pydLyx